# Why isn't this line break printing?

Tags: python

I am attempting to create an ASCII level editor in Python, but I've ran into an issue. In my `renderer` function there is a for loop that, after printing on line of the level, is supposed to print a line break. But, it doesn't seem to work. Is it something with the `newLine` function?

```
import os

class LevelEditor:

    def __init__(self, level = [], currentLine = 0, line = ""):
        self.level = level
        self.currentLine = currentLine
        self.line = line

    def renderer(self):

        for i in range(len(self.level)):
            for j in range(len(self.level[i])):
                print(self.level[i][j], end="")
            print()

    def clearScreen(self):
        if os.name == "posix":
            os.system("clear")
        elif os.name == "nt":
            os.system("cls")
        else:
            print("OS not recognized")

        print()

    def newLine(self):
        self.line = input("\n")

        self.level += [[]]

        # add line to level
        for i in range(len(self.line)):
            self.level[self.currentLine] += self.line[i]

    def loop(self):
        while(True):
            self.clearScreen()
            self.renderer()
            self.newLine()


Editor = LevelEditor()
Editor.loop()
```

Comment: Please provide expected input/output.

Comment: `level` is an empty list, so there's nothing to print.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Only the first time. Each time through the loop after that, it's clearly non-empty, but he still has the problem he's asking about.

Comment: @abarnert That's a no repro from me, then. Every time I give input, there's one more empty line.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Are you giving empty input? When I type `123`, then `456`, then `789`, I get an empty output, then `123`, then `123456`, then `123456789`. Which seems to be exactly what the OP is reporting—he's concatenating all the levels onto a single line without newlines between them, but he isn't failing to print them at all as you're claiming.

Comment: @abarnert As you say, all the input is printed in a single line - but there's still one more empty line in the output with every iteration. Anyway, it should be the OP's job to explain the code and what exactly isn't working. At the moment the question is too unclear and difficult to understand, IMO. The problem as the OP has described it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Aran-Fey It's a little unclear, but the most obvious interpretation is exactly what happens—and it's certainly not true that `level` is empty, or that it prints nothing at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try printing out what's in `self.level`. If you've entered lines `123`, `456`, `789`, what you want is presumably this:

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

… but what you have is this:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'], [], []]
```

Why? Because you add them with this:

```
self.level[self.currentLine] += self.line[i]
```

… and you never increment `self.currentLine` anywhere. You probably want to add this line to the end of `newLine`:

```
self.currentLine += 1
```

---

However, it might be simpler to just build the new line and add it, and not even bother with that `currentLine` variable. And, for that matter, you don't need a `line` attribute; that's just a local variable. Plus, you don't need a loop to convert a string into a list of characters one by one. So, you can replace the whole thing with:

```
line = input('\n')
self.level += list(line)
```

---

As a side note, you probably don't want to use `[]` as a default value for `self.level`. If you do that, and create two separate `LevelEditor` instances with default arguments, they're going to end up sharing the same list. To fix that, either do this:

```
def __init__(self, level=[]):
    self.level = list(level)
```

… or, if you want to allow *explicitly* sharing lists, but not accidentally:

```
def __init__(self, level=None):
    self.level = [] if level is None else level
```

… or, is there really any reason to allow passing in a value at all? If not:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.level = []
```